# Docx4j : SpreadsheetMLPackage - java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, excel, spring-boot, docx4j

We are trying to use the Docx4j for complex excel read(Not using apache poi for some reason).

But we do have dependencies of Apache poi as well which we couldn't use for complex excel read.

When we are trying to read the excel  then getting below exception :  Any input will be appreciated.

Line from where exception was triggered:

> SpreadsheetMLPackage xlsxPkg = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(fin);

Dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>docx4j-JAXB-Internal</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Exception:

```
INFO - Detected SpreadhseetMLPackage package
INFO - Detected SpreadhseetMLPackage package
INFO - Instantiated package of type org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.SpreadsheetMLPackage
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:982)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.CreateDocPropsExtendedPartObject(ContentTypeManager.java:574)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.newPartForContentType(ContentTypeManager.java:355)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager.getPart(ContentTypeManager.java:286)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.getRawPart(Load3.java:469)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.getPart(Load3.java:370)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.addPartsFromRelationships(Load3.java:278)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3.get(Load3.java:196)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:561)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:410)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:376)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.OpcPackage.load(OpcPackage.java:341)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(SpreadsheetMLPackage.java:114)
       org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
        ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to create an XPathFactory for the default object model: http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the XPathFactoryConfigurationException: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory: jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/K-DCP%20Engineering%20Platform/K-DCP%20ECU%20Editor/ECUEditor.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/saxon9he-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:2: Illegal configuration-file syntax
        at javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.docx4j.utils.XPathFactoryUtil.getXPathFactory(XPathFactoryUtil.java:37)
        at org.docx4j.utils.XPathFactoryUtil.newXPath(XPathFactoryUtil.java:50)
        at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsExtendedPart.<clinit>(DocPropsExtendedPart.java:69)
        ... 75 more
ERROR - Exception handler executed
```

Other dependencies used:

Apache poi : 3.17
Xalan : 2.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: XPathFactory#newInstance() failed to
>   create an XPathFactory for the default object model:
>   http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom with the
>   XPathFactoryConfigurationException:
>   javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactoryConfigurationException:
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:
>   jar:file: ..
>   saxon9he-1.0.0.jar!/META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:2:
>   Illegal configuration-file syntax

Dodgy config file in saxon9he-1.0.0.jar (not related to docx4j).  Try deleting META-INF/services/javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory from C:/Program%20Files/K-DCP%20Engineering%20Platform/K-DCP%20ECU%20Editor/ECUEditor.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/saxon9he-1.0.0.jar using some zip file editor, or upgrading saxon9he.